# Form Click Event in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, forms

I need to get html radio button data and call upgradeschema.php file, because to my data to database.

This is my html(template) file.

```
<html>
    <form **action**="..........">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="html" checked> Html<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="text"> Text<br>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="submit"><br>
</form>
</html>
```

This is my form, When click  submit button get data from form and call to upgradeschema class file then store the form data to database.

**My question is which action class i put into form action part, CaI i call directly upgradeschema call in magento2.** or how to get data from form and store database in magento 2 way.

Comment: What about the form action? It should have some URL for data submission, right? From this point, if you have URL, than you have a controller. If you have a controller and if you really need to use observer - you can register it on the controller's "predispatch" event.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between frontend JavaScript events and Magento backend events. You cannot capture a click event by Magento observer until this click does not fire request to the server side. When some call to the server side has been triggered - you can "catch" this request and data passed over this request on the server side by registering observer to the "controller predispatch" event or similar events.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain bit more. provide hints to send request to server or any  related article ping me.